# Putting different datatypes in dictionaries from what was defined

Tags: java, dictionary

**The Code:**

```
Dictionary<String, Integer> dict = new Hashtable<>();
dict.put(record);
```

Is it possible to put another datatype in a dictionary if you've already defined the datatypes for the dictionary? For example, I want to put record which is has the datatype `Data`.

Comment: Well, the whole point of generics is that the compiler can do its type checking and flag bad code at compile time instead of having it crash at runtime. You can allow subtypes as well, but you cannot just put whatever in a typed collection. Check [these chapters from Effective Java](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=4).

Comment: Your question smells of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is not to mix Integer and Data types, but likely to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it, since your path is the wrong one.

Answer (score 5):

## Sub-types, not different types

> Is it possible to put another datatype in a dictionary if you've already defined the datatypes for the dictionary?

No.

You can put in *sub-types* but not entirely *different* types. The purpose of [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) is to empower the compiler to stop you from using different types.

If your define your [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) to hold keys of type `String` that lead to a value of type `Integer`, then:

- Every key you enter into that map must be either a `String` object itself, or a subclass of `String`. 
  The `String` class is `final`, so there is no such thing as a subclass of `String.
- Every value you enter into that map must be either an `Integer` object itself, or a subclass of `Integer`.
  The `Integer` class is `final`, so there is no such thing as a subclass of `Integer`.

Suppose we defined your map with the more general types [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html). Then we can add entries where the key is any implementation of the `CharSequence` interface such as `String` and [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). And we can add entries where the value is any subclass of `Number` such as `Integer` and [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html).

```java
Map < CharSequence, Number > map =
        Map.of (
                "Alice" , Integer.valueOf ( 42 ) ,                       // String , Integer
                new StringBuilder ( "Bob" ) , Double.valueOf ( "7.8" )   // StringBuilder , Double
        );
```

## Records

If you want to replace your `String` -> `Integer` pairing with the use of [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), no need for the `Map`. Just used any `Set` or `List` implementation you want to collect objects of your record type.

```
record CatsPerPerson ( String name , int countOfCats ) {}
List< CatsPerPerson > list = 
    List.of (
        new CatsPerPerson ( "Alice" , 2 ) ,
        new CatsPerPerson ( "Bob" , 0 ) ,
        new CatsPerPerson ( "Paula Poundstone" , 12 ) 
    );
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your help. I saw both yours and AztecCodes's response a while ago but didnt reply (quite frankly didnt notice a comments section until now) but this was helpful.